# macOS git branch displays branches in less

Tags: git, git-branch, macos-high-sierra

I'm running `git` version 2.16.1 under macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 and when I
use `git branch`, the result is displayed through `less`. On the contrary, when I'm using `git branch` under Linux, the result is simply printed in stdout. How can I enforce git to work the same way it works in Linux?

`git branch` under macOS:
[image: git branch uses less in macos]

`git branch` under Linux:
[image]

Comment: Close voters: this seems like a sane question to me; what's unclear about it?

Comment: Agree with @phd. Absolutely a duplicate. (Can't re-vote after retracting my previous one, though).

Comment: Duplicates are helpful for search purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of varying defaults for the `pager.branch` setting in your Git configuration.

For a one-off pagerless `git branch`, run:

```
$ git branch --no-pager
```

To persistently disable the pager on a repo, run:

```
$ git config --local pager.branch "cat"
```

And if you want to set this globally, run:

```
$ git config --global pager.branch "cat"
```

The `git-config` docs outline this [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pagerltcmdgt).

It should go without saying that if you ever want to revert to using `less` (or `more`, or whatever other pager), just replace `cat` with that other pager in the last two commands.